# How to take items in list and reform them into json

Tags: python, json

I have 4 SEPARATED json with 4 keys `sum`, `min`, `max`, `count` with list like below:

```
"sum" :  ["columnA", "columnB", "columnC", "columnD"]

"min" :  ["columnA", "columnC"]

"max" :  ["columnB", "columnC"]

"count" : ["columnA", "columnD"]
```

How can I take them and repack into a json object like this:

```
{ "columnA" : ["sum", "min","count" ] , "columnB" : ["sum", "max"], "columnC" : ["sum", "min", "max"] }
```

Comment: `json` is a text format, not a data type.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers and then?

Comment: and then "I have 4 SEPARATED json" doesn't make sense. You either have four files or strings or whatever containing json formattted text (in which case you want to first parse them into python objects), or you already have python objects (probably dicts) eventually created from json-formatted strings, but then what you have are just plain python objects, not "json".

Comment: And actually what you posted is neither valid json not valid python...

Comment: Yes I need to parse them into something. What I mean is not to be restricted to the format. Given such 4 keys with their values, the goal is to come out with what I stated on the question in hoping that people will not be restricted by the format and feel free to restructure it to fit their way. The answer by mshsayem is a good example, he reform them into a json. Anyway, thanks for pointing out the inaccuracy on the question writing, will take extra caution next time.

Comment: "he reform them into a json" => still not - in his example, both `my_json` and `result` are plain python dicts.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for all clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For quick(development) result, try this:

```
>>> my_json = {"sum" :  ["columnA", "columnB", "columnC", "columnD"]
,"min" :  ["columnA", "columnC"]
,"max" :  ["columnB", "columnC"]
,"count" : ["columnA", "columnD"]}
>>> result = {}
>>> [result.setdefault(col,[]).append(key) for key,value in my_json.items() for col in value]
>>> result
{'columnD': ['count', 'sum'], 'columnA': ['count', 'sum', 'min'], 'columnC': ['max', 'sum', 'min'], 'columnB': ['max', 'sum']}
```

A more readable version:

```
>>> result = {}
>>> for function, columns in my_json.items():
        for column in columns:
            result.setdefault(column, []).append(function)


>>> result
{'columnD': ['count', 'sum'], 'columnA': ['count', 'sum', 'min'], 'columnC': ['max', 'sum', 'min'], 'columnB': ['max', 'sum']}
```